# In what Atlantis episode was a wraith stunner pistol shot and destroyed?

Tags: stargate, episode-identification, weapon, stargate-atlantis

In an episode of Stargate Atlantis, I recall a battle where a wraith stunner pistol was shot and destroyed/disabled. I seem to recall it was Sheppard who was using it at the time, but I could be mistaken.

Does anyone recall in which episode this occurred? I think this may have been the only time a stunner pistol was damaged like this.

Here is a photo of the damaged stunner:

[image: Battle damaged wraith stunner pistol]

Comment: https://ukm.propstoreauction.com/m/lot-details/index/catalog/299/lot/81227 - You could have bought said pistol for just £800

Comment: Yes, that's where I saw it. And I couldn't remember what episode it was from.

Comment: This is an interesting question. IIRC, the larger wraith rifles were also stunners. Not sure if they had a lethal mode that could punch a hole into stuff like that... Definitely wasn't P90 fire and replicator pistols were also stunners. Must've been wraith weapon fire, which doesn't narrow it much at all...

Comment: From my dim recollection, the way the scene played out was that the team was pinned down and trying to escape from somewhere, they were using stunners, and a wraith zapped zapped the pistol stunner sheppard was using.

Comment: Do you remember who was in charge in Atlantis, who was the Chief Medical Officer in Atlantis and was Ronan in the episode? It'll help to narrow it down a bit

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to recall any of those details.

Comment: The damage is what I might expect to see from Ronan's gun. @ForceFlow ot, have I seen you around in the past on the Sitepoint forums?

Comment: Yes, though I haven't been active there in a good while

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up watching the series again and found the damaged stunner in [Season 4, Episode 5, "Travelers"](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Travelers)

Larrin picks up the stunner from the dead wraith that Sheppard killed and discovers that it was damaged.

[image]

Additionally, stunner pistols weren't introduced until the first episode of Season 2.